# Hibernate LockOptions with timeout

Tags: java, hibernate

My Project have locking a row mechanism for hibernate 3.3.2.GA version, we are planning to uplift to hibernate 5. I am planning to make this query work in older hibernate and newer versions as well.

This is the existing query in hibernate 3.3.2.GA

This query will lock the row if the row is locked in session already, will wait until the time out and throw time out if it exceeds.

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("select aps from WritableSchool aps where aps.schoolCd = :schoolCd");
query.setParameter("schoolCd", schoolCd);
query.setTimeout(2); // seconds
query.setLockMode("aps", LockMode.UPGRADE);
List<WritableSchool> schools = query.list();
```

When we upgrade to hibernate 4 / 5 versions, time out is not working it is waiting forever for the lock to acquire if the table is locked in session already.

In hibernate 4 with the same code i tried replacing lock and time out this way
`query.setLockOptions(new LockOptions(LockMode.UPGRADE).setTimeOut(100));`

It still not able to get the time out working.

I tried  another way as well.

`session.buildLockRequest(LockOptions.NONE).setLockMode(LockMode.UPGRADE).setTimeOut(2000).lock(school);`

It is executing select.. for update  but not honoring time out however i implement.

The only solution currently i have in my hand is to override the hibernate oracle dialect and set the `shouldUseFollowOnLocking()` to return to false, that  gets the lock and honor timeout as well.

I am wondering why time out on Lockoptions by hibernate is not honoring the same. If any one have any idea on locks and time out in hibernate, please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some possible ways i found out this way we can set lock with time out compatible with hibernate 3.5.6 to current hibernate versions with out any issues.

```
Session session = ((Session) em.getDelegate());
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("select aps from WritableSchool aps where aps.schoolCd = :schoolCd"); query.setParameter("schoolCd", schoolCd); 
WritableSchool schools = query.list().get(0);
session.buildLockRequest(LockOptions.NONE).setLockMode(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE).setTimeOut(2000).lock(aliasPoolSeq);
```

2nd way but this works from 3.5.6 and all other higher versions.

```
 school = (WritableSchool ) session.get(WritableSchool .class, primaryKey,
                        new LockOptions(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE).setTimeOut(QUERY_TIMEOUT_SEC * 1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found alternate solution as well which works with different hibernate versions if you are allowed to extend hibernate dialects in your project. you can override this way

```
public class Oracle10gDialectExtension extends Oracle10gDialect implements DialectExtension
{

    @Override
    public boolean useFollowOnLocking()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```